# if or condition produce "integer expression expected"

Tags: bash

The following code produce error "integer expression expected":

```
for SOURCE_PATH in work/sources/*; do
    git diff --exit-code &>/dev/null || SOMETHING_TO_COMMIT=$?
    if [ "$SOMETHING_TO_COMMIT" -eq "0" ] || [ "$SOMETHING_TO_COMMIT" -eq "" ] ; then
        echo "NOTHING TO COMMIT FOR $SOURCE_PATH";
    else
        echo "COMMIT FOR $SOURCE_PATH"
        git -C "$DIR/$SOURCE_PATH" commit -F ${COMMIT_MESSAGE_FILE}
    fi
done
```

Error is on line `if [ "$SOMETHING_TO_COMMIT" -eq "0" ] || [ "$SOMETHING_TO_COMMIT" -eq "" ] ; then`. It seems `[ "$SOMETHING_TO_COMMIT" -eq "0" ]`or `[ "$SOMETHING_TO_COMMIT" -eq "" ]` should produce integer.

How to fix that ?

Comment: `$?` will never be an empty string, why do you need to compare with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second test compares the variable with an empty string (""), but using -eq which is for integers only, so you should change it to the = operator:

```
 if [ "$SOMETHING_TO_COMMIT" -eq "0" ] || [ "$SOMETHING_TO_COMMIT" = "" ] ; then
```

Comment: If `$SOMETHING_TO_COMMIT` actually contains an empty string, the first `-eq "0"` will get an error. So you should use `=` there, as well. Or change the order of the tests. But in actuality, it will never be empty.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to store the exit codes in variables at all. If the `git diff` can return a non-zero exit code on failure like the most common Linux/Unix commands, you can directly use it in the if conditional as

```
if ! git diff --exit-code &>/dev/null ; then
    echo "NOTHING TO COMMIT FOR $SOURCE_PATH";
```

The `!` operator asserts true of the if-condition *only* if the `git diff` was *not* successful and there were no changes to commit. Also you should change your script to assert true on the if-condition and fail on the else part as

```
if git diff --exit-code &>/dev/null ; then
    echo "COMMIT FOR ${SOURCE_PATH}"
    git -C "$DIR/${SOURCE_PATH}" commit -F "${COMMIT_MESSAGE_FILE}"
else
    echo "NOTHING TO COMMIT FOR ${SOURCE_PATH}";
fi
```

which makes it more readable and efficient.

Comment: I accepted the @netizen answer because it's a direct answer to my question but i upvote yours !

Answer (score 1):

Between the two current answers, there is the realization that you don't have to make a conditional assignment to `SOMETHING_TO_COMMIT`. Just assign the exit status, zero or not, to the parameter; then it is guaranteed to have some non-empty integer value.

```
git diff --exit-code &>/dev/null; SOMETHING_TO_COMMIT=$?
if [ "$SOMETHING_TO_COMMIT" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "NOTHING TO COMMIT FOR $SOURCE_PATH";
else
    echo "COMMIT FOR $SOURCE_PATH"
    git -C "$DIR/$SOURCE_PATH" commit -F ${COMMIT_MESSAGE_FILE}
fi
```

As Inian points out, you don't need to save the exit status if you are only going to make *one* comparison; you can use the `git` command itself as the `if` condition. Saving the value is useful when you might need to make *multiple* comparisons:

```
some_command; status=$?
if [ "$status" -eq 0 ]; then
  ...
elif [ "$status" -eq 1 ]; then
  ...
else
  ...
fi
```